# Issue with usecontext api - React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, use-context

I am working on a dashboard where when user login, I make a request to an API to confirm the log in details and then I save the response to localStorage(to be able to persist users) and at the same time I have an AuthContext which I also set to the response. After this is done, the user sees the dashboard main page first and the data here is gotten from the useContext Api, instead of me making another api call ....my problem is this works fine when user logs in, but when user reloads, the app breaks because it sees the context value as null...which is the default......Also, if I try getting the data directly from localStorage, it works fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.